# How to disable/enable fast forward functionality of AVPlayer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios10, avplayer

I am Using AVPlayer to play Video files in ios swift. The requirement is,  I want to disable fast forward for certain users. is this achievable? 
 Please let me know is any alternative or is there some method to disable it in swift

Comment: All you need to do is set the rate of `AVPlayer` object. the [rate property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate) manages the rate at which the media is played.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 self.playerController.setValue(true, forKey: "requiresLinearPlayback")
```

Doc.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/1627633-requireslinearplayback